# Issue with a conditional sub query

Tags: mysql

I have the following table:

```
value    tag    main_tag
------------------------
    1    tag_A  ABC
   -1    tag_C  ABC
   -1    tag_A  BCD
    1    tag_C  BCD
   -1    tag_A  ABC
    1    tag_C  ABC
   -1    tag_A  BCD
    1    tag_C  BCD
   -1    tag_C  BCD
```

As demonstrated, there are three columns `value`, `tag`, `main_tag`. Under each `main_tag` there are several other `tag` s. I want to get the rows where sum of `value` s of each `tag` is equal to zero under each `main_tag`.

This is the query I tried,

```
SELECT * 
FROM foo 
WHERE ( WHERE sum(value) = 0 GROUP BY tag) 
GROUP BY main_tag ;
```

First I am trying to find the sum of values `GROUP BY tag` and then I am using `GROUP BY main_tag`. But it is not working.

Output Should be :

```
value    tag    main_tag
------------------------
    1    tag_A  ABC 
   -1    tag_C  ABC 
   -1    tag_A  ABC 
    1    tag_C  ABC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure that I got it right, but:

```
select tag, main_tag
from foo 
group by tag, main_tag
having sum(value) = 0;
```

retrieves tag, main_tag where sum(value) is 0. You can join this result with the original table as:

```
select f.* 
from foo f
join ( 
    select tag, main_tag
    from foo 
    group by tag, main_tag
    having sum(value) = 0
) as t
    on t.tag = f.tag
   and t.main_tag = f.main_tag;
```

Answer (score 2):

## Analytical Functions

Learn them.  Love them.

https://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-2-introducing-window-functions/

```
select value, tag, main_tag
from (
  select value, tag, main_tag
    ,sum(value) over (partition by main_tag, tag) keep_zeros
  from foo
)
where keep_zeros = 0;
```